# embedding an image in stylesheet instead of using img tag

Tags: css

I encountered this code

```
 .happy-icon
    height 22px
    width 22px
    background base64('../assets/pencil-default.png') no-repeat center
```

What is the advantage of embedding this image in the stylesheet instead of  tag ? 
What is the advantate of using base64 call ?

Based on some of the resopnses I received.. if this is meant to optimize..
then the image has to be used in only one place I assume..

so considering the below .. the image will be converted into data string twice and un-necessarily increase the size of the css... Am i right ?

```
.class-1
   base64('../some-image.jpg')

.class-2
   base64('../some-image.jpg')
```

Comment: @simon This is not Sass (note the lack of colons).  It's probably Stylus, but only the OP knows for sure.

Comment: @cimmanon thank you for correcting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It saves on HTTP requests which optimises your sites speed because base64 converts the image in to a data string. However the way you've written it wouldn't work, you need to first convert the image to base64 and then use that code

https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: it'll still work, increasing the size of your CSS is far better for page speed than multiple HTTP requests. Some devs use base64 inline on their markup, which makes the markup fairly illegible but improves speed too.

Comment: but if the browser is caching images.. then it's not going to make multiple calls ..

Comment: It's about the initial request, the first time the page is loaded the number of requests that need to be made

Comment: Even for the initial request.. is the browser going to load the image multiple times ?

Comment: Nope, essentially lets just say that loading the CSS takes up one request and loading the img takes up another so by converting the image to base64 it's now code that can be combined with the CSS, so only one request is needed rather than two. If you extend this to multiple images the number of requests is reduced drastically and the sites speed is improved

Answer (score 1):

This gets inlined in the build process. This is mostly useful where you can't deploy images or other static assets, or maybe some niche performance use case.

Less HTTP requests = less overhead, but without actual performance testing, I would be skeptical of this.

Answer (score 1):

The technical difference in embedding is reducing the amount of HTTP calls you get. So before embedding you have two files to be downloaded and after you have only one.

It has also the side effect: it unnecessarily increases the size of your CSS. Why unnecessarily?

Imagine the case that your image is displayed only on one page which is visited once a year, so an average user will never see that image. But the CSS file will contain its contents. Without embedding this image would be lazily loaded only once when you come to a specific page.

So this is the main difference. You put everything in one module or separate modules and load them only when it is needed. Both ways could be useful, both could be useless.